# Consume webservices through Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-emulator

i'm using Android Virtual Device with Android 3.2, and i try to use webservices.

I added the line in the manifest which allows my application to go on the Internet :
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

I have access to the Internet through my emulated device, on my browser i can go on my local website with "`http://192.168.2.114/test`".

I use the `vtwsclib-1.4` (`for vtiger`) and there are some functions to `login`, do queries, ... (consume webservices of the `Client Relationship Management`)

I tested with a simple project on Eclipse and everything works, but when i try to do it through the emulator ..

My problem is that i can't consume webservices of the crm. Do you have an idea of the problem ? I don't have any error message.

I think about Firewall, but don't know what to change

Thx

Comment: Accessing local system is not same as accessing internet. Are you accessing internet through a proxy?

Comment: No i'm not accessing internet through a proxy

Comment: can you post your code so that i can understand what you want?

Comment: have you tried ksoap to consume web service in android